# How can I concatenate two structs type variables in c++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, memcpy

I'e been trying for sometime to concatenate some struct (I defined) type variables into a bigger one. What I got is basically like this:

I have a struct and two variables of type struct**.
I declare a third one struct C and I want to concatenate A and B into C.
What I tried is something like this (I don't have the code in front of me right now so I'll write something very similar with some names changed as I don't remember them.

```
struct** A, B;
struct** C;
```

(I know A and B as I receive them by calling another function)

I allocate memory for C like this.

```
C = (struct**)malloc(sizeof(A)+sizeof(B));
```

And I move A and B with memcpy like this.

```
memcpy(&C, &A, sizeof(A));
memcpy(&C + sizeof(A), &C, sizeof(B));
```

It's obvious that what I've done is not correct as it seems after all of this C contains only A.
I'm pretty sure the problem is from "**", I can't handle pointers to pointers that well.
Can anybody give me some advice regarding my issue?
I also don't want to use Handles, I have to use memcpy/memmove.

---

[update from comment:]

My struct are all the same type.

Comment: Completely unclear what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: `&C+sizeof(A)` what does this suppose to mean in memcpy ?

Comment: "*`struct**`*" is not a valid type. "*`struct** A, B`*" won't compile nor would "*`struct** C;`*" do.

Comment: If you're programming in C++, why the C tag? And why use `malloc` and `memcpy` (which might do undesirable things if you, for example, have complex data or virtual functions)? And lastly, why pointer to pointer? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't really know what is so unclear.. I want to concatenate A and B.

Comment: pointer to pointer because that's I'm required to do.. I didn't choose them.

Comment: And what does "concatenating structs" mean? I know about concatenating strings, "a"+"b"=="ab". But structs with arbitrary variables inside? Are you searching arrays?

Comment: And you do know that when you use `&C` you will get a pointer to pointer to pointer? And that e.g. `sizeof(A)` is not the size of the structure or what `A` points to, but the size of the *pointer*.

Comment: &C + sizeof(A) was something i tried to copy the content from B where I remained after copying A. Anyway, assume that my code there is incorrect (which it is), I need a solution..

Comment: "Required", "have to"?   Is this homework?

Comment: You should pick one language. C and C++ are different languages, even more as it comes to memory allocation.

Answer (score 4):

You already have a `struct A a;` and a `struct B b;` defined somewhere.
To concatenate them into a `struct C` you do this:

```
struct A a;
struct B b;

struct C{
    struct A a;
    struct B b;
};

struct C c;
c.a = a;
c.b = b;
```

No pointers or `memcpy` required.

Edit: Since `a` and `b` are of the same type you can somewhat shorten it to this:

```
struct Something a, b;

struct C{
    struct Something[2];
};

struct C c;
c[0] = a;
c[1] = b;
```

In C++ you would do something like this:

```
using C = std::array<Something, 2>;
C c{a, b};
```

Comment: My bad, I wrote confusing stuff. My struct are all the same type. I wrote struct as in general.

Comment: @Andreiasd I hope this is what you mean by same type. Obviously you cannot fit 2 structs in the space of 1 of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

[Best for C]

Just use an array.

Assuming `struct A` is defined an array on the stack

```
struct A a1 = {...}; /* some initialisation here */
struct A a2 = {...}; /* more initialisation here */

struct A a[2];
a[0] = a1;
a[1] = a2;
```

or allocate it dynamically:

```
struct A * pa = malloc(2 * sizeof *pa);
if (NULL != pa)
{
  pa[0] = a1;
  pa[1] = a2;

  /* use pa */

  free(pa);
}
else
{
  /* handle malloc error */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off, your code has a bug:

```
memcpy(&C, &A, sizeof(A));
memcpy(&C + sizeof(A), &C, sizeof(B));
```

Should probably be

```
memcpy(&C, &A, sizeof(A));
memcpy(&C + sizeof(A), &B, sizeof(B));
```

You were copying C back into C rather than B.

Second, if you ever find yourself playing with pointers like this you've probably got a design problem somewhere along the lines. If you REALLY want to merge two structs together, why not have struct C simply contain both struct A and B?

If you REALLY want struct C to have nothing bot primitives, dude, just do the work to assign each field individually. Is it really all that much work? I guess it makes sense to generalize it if you expect these fields to change a lot.  But this sort of "clever code" is the exact sort of things which will bite you in the ass later down the line.