# Easy access to multiple struct arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct, arduino

I have 2 struct arrays

```
myStruct leds_left[20];
myStruct leds_right[20];
```

I need a way to combine the two structs, so that I can use it like:

```
*(structPtr[10]) // points to element of leds_left[10]
*(structPtr[30]) // points to element of leds_right[10]
```

I already tried the following:

```
myStruct ** structPtr = (myStruct**) malloc((20 + 20) * sizeof(myStruct*));
structPtr[0] = &leds_right[15]; //just with one element for testing

*(structPtr[0]) = newValue;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you want to merge the structs together. Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32315939/7255359

Comment: The code you already have would work, if you assign all 40 of the pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure that `leds_left` and `leds_right` are really allocated in consecutive memory they must be "structured together". This in combination with a `union` could provide what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { int i; /* ... */ } myStruct;

static union {
  struct {
    myStruct leds_left[20];
    myStruct leds_right[20];
  };
  myStruct leds_all[40];
} data;

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    data.leds_left[i].i = 1 + i;
    data.leds_right[i].i = -(1 + i);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i) {
    printf(" %d", data.leds_all[i].i);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested with gcc in cygwin on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -o test-struct-array test-struct-array.c 

$ ./test-struct-array.exe 
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -11 -12 -13 -14 -15 -16 -17 -18 -19 -20

$
```

**Attention!**

Packing and alignment could become an issue (depending on what components `myStruct` actually contains).

Comment: wow, this would be a really nice solution! Unfortunately myStruct is not defined by my own, and it seems like it does not have a default constructor.

Therefore the Line `myStruct leds_all[40];`

shows the error: _union member '<anonymous union>::all' with non-trivial
 'myStruct::myStruct()'_ 

is there another way to use your nice solution, which supports non-default-ctor structs?

Comment: @shoutcool 1. There are no constructors in C. (Wrong tag?) 2. You may not allocate memory (neither `static`/`extern` nor with `malloc`) for incomplete `struct`. If you only have pointer to incomplete `struct`, the above solution is beyond your possibilities. In this case, forget about your "optimization" - you have not control whether allocation allows this.

Comment: @shoutcool The best you could have in this case is an array of pointers to these `struct`s. [Everything can be solved with another level of indirection.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection)

Comment: Ok.... bad news :( Nevertheless your solution is a really nice way to access multiple struct arrays. Therefore i mark the question as answered, even if i cannot use it. Too bad that my structs are incomplete.

Comment: i already tried with array of pointers.  see my code sample in the question. my idea was to loop over all struct arrays (leds_left, leds_right..) and hold a pointer of each element in a new array. what is wrong with my code?

Comment: @shoutcool Pointers to incomplete `struct`s are often used to provide something like "handles to opaque objects/data". What you cannot do with them: accessing components, allocate storage, etc. Instead, such pointers to opaque data are used exclusively as parameters for dedicated functions. (This is some kind of light-weight OOP in C. Saw it very often in glib for example.) May be, you have to check your problem again and to elaborate your question a little bit. I would not yet give up at this point...

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution which is good enough for me. Because the nice way with an combined array is not possible, i just wrote a function witch is checking the index and then accessing the right element in one of the arrays.

```
    void setLED(int number, CRGB color){
       if (number < leds_left_size){
          leds_left[number] = color;
       }else if (number >= leds_left_size && number < leds_left_size + leds_top_size){
          leds_top[number - leds_left_size] = color;
       }else if (number >= leds_left_size + leds_top_size && number < leds_top_size + leds_left_size + leds_right_size){
          leds_right[number - leds_left_size - leds_top_size] = color;
       }else{
          leds_bottom[number - leds_left_size - leds_top_size - leds_right_size] = color;
       }
    }
```

It does not exactly anwer my question, but it works as a workaround

Comment: This surprises me a little bit: Assignment is something else which is not available for incomplete `struct`s. May be, your `struct` is not really incomplete. I'm afraid we still didn't see/found your actual problem...

Comment: If your assign `CRGB color` to `leds_left`, I would assume `leds_left[number]` is an array of this type.

Comment: yes you are right: `CRGB leds_left[leds_left_size];` and CRGB is a struct. If you want to take a look at it [here](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/master/pixeltypes.h#L90) is the code on github